# How do I lubricate a noisy fan?

Tags: hardware, fan, physical-environment

I have a case fan that can be quite noisy. I can take the fan out of the case, peel back the sticker on the center to expose access to the bearings, and lubricate the fan. Thus far, I've been using a few drops of WD-40, but after a few days the fan makes noise again.

Obviously, I could buy a new fan, but knowing how to lubricate a noisy fan seems somewhat useful, as not all hardware hardware has replaceable fan units.

Does anyone know why the WD-40 only works temporarily, and what I should be using instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd try [3 in one](http://www.3inone.com/products/multi-purpose/) oil.  WD-40 is mostly a solvent, 3 in one should give you a longer term solution.

Answer (score 19):

You should really replace the fan. The ball bearing has probably seized and adding lubrication will only help for a few days. 
As a temporary lubricant you could use about anything with low friction.

Comment: Worse, most fans are sleeve bearing and don't last that long.  Purchase a quality ball bearing fan.

Comment: +1: It's a cheap part, and one that shouldn't require maintenance during its design life. (Shouldn't use WD-40 anyway; 3-in-1 oil for bearings.)

Comment: Disagree.  I've seen many noisy fans "get better", and often last the life of the machine (4-5+ years total).

Comment: +1: The amount of labor you spend relubricating the fan will almost certainly eclipse the cost of replacing the fan.

Comment: I've oiled fans and had them run for years afterwards.  3-in-1 or sewing machine oil.  Useful for high quality but old fans.  Not so useful for fans that were cheap to start with.

Answer (score 3):

I do what you're suggesting quite frequently.  I put a few drops of WD40 down into the bearing, and then I use a high pressure air hose to spin the fan real fast.  I then take a paper towel and wipe out the gunk.  I might repeat the process one more time.  Then I put a drop or two of 3 in 1 oil in there and give it another good spin.

After having done this dozens of times with fans of various size and make, I would say that it restores fan life for a considerable period.  Sometimes the fan will start chattering again after a year or so and I'll repeat the process.  In only a few situations have I ever had to buy a new fan.  It's not that I'm cheap, it's that finding a replacement fan can be an irritating process..especially if it's some goofy chipset fan with a unique mount.  This process only takes ten minutes, and so far I've found it less time consuming than trying to find a replacement.

One exception I make is for power supply fans.  I don't open those things up anymore.  I typically just buy a new supply.

Comment: You clearly have a lot of free time.

Comment: Yep, ten whole minutes every now and then.

Answer (score 2):

[Aerosol Teflon](http://www2.dupont.com/Consumer_Lubricants/en_US/products/dryfilm.html) is another option.

Answer (score 1):

Clean it out and use a vegetable based oil with a pin hole oil lubricator. It looks like a pen. You can get them at a hardware store. Or just replace the fan you cheapo.

Answer (score 0):

[I notice that amazon is offering one heck of a deal on 55 gallon drums of lube](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005MR3IVO) - almost two thirds off!  I'm not sure how well this type of lube would work on a fan, and the fact that it's water-based would make me a little wary of using it on an electronic component, [but seeing as how your fan should probably be replaced anyway](https://serverfault.com/a/94990/118258), it seems like a perfect opportunity to try something a little bit "out there."

Answer (score 0):

The Definitive Proper Method to lubricate a noisy fan,
it will work on most fans and it will continue to work
longer than expected in most cases.

WD40 is a great start only, and clears some old oil crap out,
but then dries out completely, and I really like 
WD40 for this action, if a fan is grimy, use it and
wait a day or blow-out or dap-out excess WD40.

The Method That Really Works: 
DuraLube - TRUST ME
An ink syringe or regular syringe with DuraLube
use 1 or 2 or 3 drops only,
1 drop is for a near working fan,
2 drops for a lightly dirty or larger fan,
3 drops for an ugly stuck but moving sleeve bearing,

I've used everything including Slick50,
Nothing works better than DuraLube on computer Fans
and they run one and a half to 3 years longer 
and whats more amazing is you can do it again 
on the same fan 3 years later.

Do It - be unsuprised at how you forget that
the fan ever had a problem, work really good on Fridge fans.

Now I need a way to do this for fans without holes,
if anyone knows a definitive way, please let us know.